# How i can add video, audio and image sitemap in existing wordpress sitemap

Tags: sitemap

I want to use WordPress default sitemap but this is not included image, video, and audio ( podcast ) sitemap.

Can anyone tell me how I can add manually which keeps automatically updating with new data?

Don't want to use any plugins

Comment: I think this is the default provider code: [class-wp-sitemaps-posts.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/6.0-branch/wp-includes/sitemaps/providers/class-wp-sitemaps-posts.php). At first glance it looks like it includes any post type marked public except attachments, although you could add that back in with a wp_sitemaps_post_types filter. Are the images and videos attachment type? How have you set up your podcasts type? Do you want to include all images etc. in the map or just a selection, and how would you configure that?

Comment: But as always it's going to be easier to find a plugin that someone's already written and tested to do this for you - or at least take inspiration from - rather than having to figure out how to do this and write your own code.